# System wide keyboard and mouse clicks in JAVA?

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm working on a JAVA VNC replacement. I'm using [JNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/)! for detecting key strokes and mouse clicks. However I need to perform the corresponding actions on the server. How do I perform key strokes and mouse clicks?
One option would be to go with Robot but however Robot works only if the application is in focus (will not work if the application is minimized). Is there any other alternative?

Comment: *"Robot works only if the application is in focus"* - You mean that whatever program has focus will receive the events, which is true, but that's true for normal operations as well.  `Robot` will send key strokes and mouse clicks to the OS, which, based on the mouse position and focused window/component, will determine who gets that event.  Maybe you might like to expand on what it is you hope to achieve...

Comment: Do you mean if another application like Chrome is in focus while my JAVA program is running in an inactive window; Chrome will receive the key strokes?

Comment: thank you! it worked perfectly. May i know how i can prevent default keyboard and mouse behavior? i don't want the keyboard to send signals to the local machine.